# fix my apt update 404 ip not found

Tags: 20.04, repository, software-sources

Can someone explain to me what is happening in this image? I'm relatively new to Ubuntu and I'm unsure how to fix this.

[image: apt update error message]

None of my repositories are updating anything. I've tried replacing all of the repositories with the stock ones I found below, but none of them seem to be able to connect, which I'm assuming is the error. Which is weird, because I just did an `apt update` last night but now I want to install Java and nothing is working.

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
```

I've tried deleting contents of sources.list and reverting with the software updater but that seems to crash for 20.04 when I click revert so I'm sol with that.

Comment: That PPA is severly outdated and perhaps not maintained. So better remove it. Last update was in 2018. Look here for details https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer. You may download the .deb and install it with dpkg, but may not work.

Comment: Sorry that stuff doesn't help guys. The default Ubuntu 20.04 repositories aren't working and I know the danielrichter one is old. I just need to get the default repo sources.ilist file working again as it's not. Does someone have a copy I can download and try or can send me their sources of the ones above aren't correct?

Comment: Just to be clear. The sources above are my current sources.list file as well as the danielrichter source. I need someone to help me figure out why none of them are connecting. I have WiFi so whats up with those? They are for Ubuntu 20.04 and that's why they have the "focal" tag near the end. Thanks for the help

Comment: Your output shows all of your sources updating properly...except for the PPA. Going forward, please copy/paste text instead of posting images of text.

Answer (score 2):

The message says that you have enabled a PPA that is no longer proving packages for your new version of Ubuntu 20.04.
This can happen when you setup a PPA for Ubuntu 18.04, then upgrade your Ubuntu, and that PPA has no longer packages for the new version of Ubuntu (in this case, *focal* or Ubuntu 20.04).

Although the message says that the IP address is no found, the real issue is that the PPA has no support for Ubuntu 20.04.

When you remove a PPA, you need to take care of what happens with the orphan packages. Because those orphan packages will stay there and likely never get updated again.

In your specific case with `grub-customizer`, we can see from https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer/+packages that the package has actually been added as an official package to the newer versions of Ubuntu (starting from Ubuntu 19.04). That is, it is a case where a package, `grub-customizer`, has been promoted from a PPA to appear in Ubuntu for everyone to use.

Therefore, in your case, use the GUI tool to disable this specific PPA. Then, perform a package update and a package upgrade. Finally, verify the version of the `grub-customizer` package.

Here are the commands if you do not use the graphical interface,

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ apt policy grub-customizer
grub-customizer:
  Installed: 5.1.0-2
  Candidate: 5.1.0-2
  Version table:
 *** 5.1.0-2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
$
```

You should get the version `5.1.0-2` as I do above.

Comment: Yes but if I remove that I'm still going to have the error where the default Ubuntu 20.04 repositories don't work still would I not? That is what im pretty sure of and how would I fix it? Unless I'm wrong. I am a little confused.

Comment: @user25832 after you remove the PPA and run `sudo apt update`, everything will be fine, as far as we can see from what you posted